# Can't get logstash to work with upstart script

Tags: ubuntu, logstash

I've installed logstash on my headless server but I'm having a few problems getting it to work from the upstart script with `sudo service logstash start`.
This is the output I get from `/var/log/logstash/logstash.log` is [here](http://pastebin.com/AcdiUSM6) but I can't see anything obvious in there.

with the upstart script being (/etc/init/logstash.conf)
    # logstash - agent instance
    #

```
description     "logstash agent"

start on virtual-filesystems
stop on runlevel [06]

# Respawn it if the process exits
respawn

# We're setting high here, we'll re-limit below.
limit nofile 65550 65550

setuid logstash
setgid logstash

# You need to chdir somewhere writable because logstash needs to unpack a few
# temporary files on startup.
console log
script
  # Defaults
  PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
  LS_HOME=/var/lib/logstash
  LS_HEAP_SIZE="500m"
  LS_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=${LS_HOME}"
  LS_LOG_FILE=/var/log/logstash/logstash.log
  LS_USE_GC_LOGGING=""
  LS_CONF_DIR=/etc/logstash/conf.d
  LS_OPEN_FILES=16384
  LS_NICE=19
  LS_OPTS="--debug"

  # Override our defaults with user defaults:
  [ -f /etc/default/logstash ] && . /etc/default/logstash

  HOME="${HOME:-$LS_HOME}"
  JAVA_OPTS="${LS_JAVA_OPTS}"
  # Reset filehandle limit
  ulimit -n ${LS_OPEN_FILES}
  cd "${LS_HOME}"

  # Export variables
  export PATH HOME JAVA_OPTS LS_HEAP_SIZE LS_JAVA_OPTS LS_USE_GC_LOGGING
  test -n "${JAVACMD}" && export JAVACMD

  exec nice -n ${LS_NICE} /opt/logstash/bin/logstash agent -f "${LS_CONF_DIR}" -l "${LS_LOG_FILE}" ${LS_OPTS}
end script
```

With the logstash conf file being:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
  date {
  match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    host => localhost
  }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Nothing seems to even though there is definitely stuff happening in the apache log.

However, when I take the interesting stuff out of the upstart script (the stuff inbetween the `script` and `end script` and run it as a shell script, it works perfectly and I can see stuff coming into the logs.
Can anyone give me some pointers on why this is happening?
I'm running Ubuntu server 14.04 server and installed `logstash=1.4.2-1-2c0f5a1`

Comment: Any messages in `/var/log/message` and  `/var/log/logstash/` ? Have you tried testing your config with `${path_to}/logstash -t -f ${path_to_config}` ?

Comment: The log output from `/var/log/logstash/logstash.conf is here: http://pastebin.com/AcdiUSM6. The config file works fine as I am able to run it from the command line, just not when run as a service.

Comment: and you probably run tests as `root` and run service as `logstash` ? :) try testing from `logstash` user. try clearing log file before next run to see what is recent output.

Comment: You were absolutely right! I was running the test as `root` and the service as `logstash` user.  It definitely looks like a user issue but I still can't figure it out. The debug logs from the test run as root which works are here (http://pastebin.com/pzc634Xt) and the logs from the service (run as logstash which doesn't work are here: http://pastebin.com/CKp7Lwpq). Can you offer any more advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I suppose this can be an answer now. Looks like your tests were run as `root` user. and your service is running as `logstash`. 
Your logs from tests do not show any errors. But I think your problem is with file permissions.
Please check that config files are readable for user `logstash` and log files are writable for him.
Plus, since that process should be able to read apache log files directly, check if `logstash` is to read them as well.
If logstash is configured to listen for incoming network connections, check of ports configured are higher than 1024.

Also you can try running your tests as `logstash` user:

something like that:

```
su -c "/path/to/logstash -t -f /path/to/config" logstash
```

Comment: Thank you! The issue was down to the apache log not being readable. Can't believe I've been stuck for so long with something so obvious!